# how can I solve this error in playwright tests?

Tags: playwright

I have this code for testing my form

```
import { expect, test } from '@playwright/test'

test('Form test', async ({ page }) => {
  await expect(page.locator('#feedback_form'))

  await page.locator('input#name[type="text"]').fill('John Doe')
  await page.locator('input#email[type="email"]').fill('troum@outlook.com')
  await page.locator('input#phone[type="text"]').fill('+47 89 89678 90')
  await page.locator('input#subject[type="text"]').fill('Test subject')
  await page.locator('input#purpose[type="text"]').fill('Test purpose')
  await page.locator('input#contactWay[type="text"]').fill('Via e-mail')
  await page
    .locator('textarea#message')
    .fill('Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text')

  await page.click('button[type="submit"]', { force: true })
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'scrapingant.png' })
})
```

but I've got this problems for each browsers

[it's my screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y30wx.png)

Answer (score 1):

try to use different selectors if its still not working,go for  playwright Codegen's generated locator using command *`npx playwright codegen`* as i was facing the same issue and it worked for me even though i was using unique locator.

Answer (score 0):

Complete the assertion first:

```js
await expect(page.locator('#feedback_form')).toBeVisible()
```

Then You can modify your selector a bit like this and try:

```js
await page.locator('input#name').fill('John Doe')
```

Or, you can do a `click` before fill and try:

```js
await page.locator('input#name').click().fill('John Doe')
```

Comment: hm...now it's failed on toBeVisible()

 Error: expect(received).toBeVisible()
    Call log:
      - expect.toBeVisible with timeout 5000ms
      - waiting for selector "#feedback_form"